# Iterate loop in every second until the video length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a video. suppose the length of the video is 0:10 sec (10 second). Also have array of array data structure like [[100,100],[20,20],[50,50],[10,10],[30,30]]. In the every sub array have two values which is represent the [x,y] coordinates. The length of the parent array is equal to the video length. I want to do that, whenever start the video the loop is start to iterate until the video length , also iterate the array of array until the length of video length and save the x and y coordinate in the state variable. How can i do it. please give the solution.

```
video length :0:05 sec

array of array :[[100,100],[20,20],[50,50],[10,10],[30,30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function with `setTimeout`. If the second variable is less than the video length call the function again.

The function is initially called with [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) which is called once when the component is mounted (empty dependency array).

In this working example I'm  [`mapping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) over the state and log each coordinate pair just to show how the output works.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Pass in the data to the component
function Example({ videoLen, data }) {

  // Initialise the state with an empty array
  const [ coords, setCoords ] = useState([]);

  // The looping function uses `setTimeout`.
  function loop(sec = 0) {

    // Update the state by preserving the previous
    // state and adding the array stored at data[sec] to it
    setCoords(prev => [ ...prev, data[sec] ]);

    // If the sec variable is less than the
    // length of the video call loop again with
    // an incremented sec variable 
    if (sec < +videoLen - 1) {
      setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++sec);
    } 
    
  }

  // Call `loop` once when the component
  // is mounted
  useEffect(() => loop(), []);

  // `map` over each coord pair in state
  // and add return some JSX
  return (
    <div>
      {coords.map(coord => {
        const [ x, y ] = coord;
        return <p>X: {x} Y:{y}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const data = [[100,100],[20,20],[50,50],[10,10],[30,30]];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example videoLen="5" data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```